# Angular and rxjs - do I need connect or refCount?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Basically, I asked about reusing the data from observables yesterday, then I asked around other places as well and read some more then I figured, why not just hold an observable and manipulate the data with `map` operators.

So I'm making just one HTTP request, store the observable to some variable and manipulate it there. The code works, but I'm not sure if I'm using `.publishReplay(1).refCount()` correctly, or should I use `connect`? Or, do I even *need* any of that? Also, is there any possible memory leak that could come out of this service?

Here's the code to service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersApiService {

  private readonly baseUrl: string = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';
  resource$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.resource$ = this.http.get<IUserDetails[]>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        console.log('"getUsers" successfully called!');
      }),
      map((data: any) => {
        return data.data;
      })
    ).publishReplay(1).refCount();
  }

  getUsers(): Observable<IUser[]> {
    return this.resource$.pipe(
      map((data: IUserDetails[]) => {
        return <IUser[]>data.map((u) => {
          return {
            id: u.id,
            name: `${u.first_name} ${u.last_name}`
          };
        });
      })
    );
  }

  getUserById(id: number): Observable<IUserDetails> {
    return this.resource$.pipe(
      map((data) => {
        return <IUserDetails>data.find(x => x.id === id);
      })
    );
  }

}
```

And the working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/3S8iKbvrrGOj9netd8sM?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I'm using .publishReplay(1).refCount() correctly

Yes, you are. You can also use `shareReplay(1)` instead.

> or should I use connect?

`refCount()` already connects for you when the first subscriber comes along (and disconnects when all observers have unsubscribed).

> do I even need any of that

If you want to hold it as an observable, yes. Otherwise you will query the backend over and over again. You could, however, of course also just memorize the last emission:

```
private resource: Observable<IUserDetails[]>;

constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get(/* … */).subscribe(data => this.resource = data);
}

getUserById(id: number): IUserDetails {
    return this.resource.find(x => x.id === id);
}
```

> Also, is there any possible memory leak that could come out of this service?

No, because `HttpClient` completes its return observable, which means the source of your multicasted observable is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate a bit what the 1 in shareReplay represents?

Comment: The `1` represents the number of values that you want to replay (since you're using a `ReplaySubject`).

Comment: Yes, I'll use this for a menu. Which i get from the backend and it has a lot of items. So I'm thinking if i load it once, i can use the data throughout the whole app. Menu will not change that often. If at all. It's just too much data to store it in some json file. Also, if user reloads the page, a new request is made, correct?

Comment: Yes, reloading will trigger a new request.

Comment: Then i think (or hope) this is the best approach here. Everything else is just querying the backend on each menu click just for displaying submenus. It seemed a bit much.

Comment: There's a lot of approaches: caching with some cache invalidation timeout or refreshing the data on demand when you know in your app that it has changed. The above cannot handle either of those things. But it depends on your requirements; if you don't need it, you don't need it.

Comment: Can you direct me somewhere where i could read more on cache timeouts? That would make some sense, too

Comment: I don't have a good standalone resource for that (and off-site resources are off-topic on SO anyway). Just keep diving into rxjs and its operators. Ben Lesh also has a lot of good videos on Youtube about rxjs in general.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to reuse the http call why not use the share operator instead. It basically handles the publish and refCount for you behind the scenes.

[Documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md)

Comment: Not sure where or how I'd use share. You mean in the component or the service? I'm pretty new to rxjs, so any additional explanation would be helpful.